# Javascript - Multiple SELECT boxes, remove 'SELECTED' options

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops, select

We're wanting to rank people in order, but don't want to allow the same option to be selected more than once:

```
Person Number 1
<select name="person1">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

Person Number 2
<select name="person2">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

Person Number 3
<select name="person3">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

So here, if someone chooses option 1 in the first person box, all the option boxes would be repopulated with that option removed (or disabled).

Obviously the first option - null 'Please Select an Option' must be ignored.

I would also need some kind of 'reset' functionality?

No idea where to start with this, any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Check the .change() event in jQuery.

Comment: Are you populating all of the dropdowns everytime a any of the dropdowns is changed, or only when the previous is changed? i.e. User selects item 3 from person3, does this refresh dropdown 1. Or if user selects item 3 from person1 does this only refresh dropdown 2 and not 3.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have N persons that you want to rank from 1 to N (there's nobody left out of the ranking).

If JavaScript components are an acceptable option for your context, then I would suggest you use the «Sortable» component :

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

It could give a better user experience than having multiple "select" elements.

**EDIT** : Ok I see from the comments that you really want to use N "select". As suggested by Flea777 you should look at the .change() event of JQuery, and set the "disabled" attribute on the "option" entries which have already been selected :
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp

Comment: I think you may be slightly confused with what the OP is asking, I believe he is asking for 3 dropdowns to be populated from the same list, but essentially not to allow the same value to be selected multiple times.

Comment: @Nunners : I believe that "ranking people" means "sorting people", and there is no «pure HTML solution» to do that. Since he will need to use some JavaScript to disable the entries in the subsequent "select", then why not use a better looking way to solve the use-case? That was my reasoning here.

Comment: I really like the idea of using sortable, however this doesn't work with mobile phone, tablets etc. My idea was to use some form of JavaScript function to go through the options and then use PHP to validate also - should they get around - or disable the JS.

Comment: @BigDistance For your situation of validating with JS and then with PHP, instead of re-populating the items each time why not just check none of the other dropdowns have the same value and pop-up an alert to warn them? You can then handle it more with the PHP.

Comment: @geceo My apologies I think I now understand why you gave your answer, my thinking was a little off :)

Comment: @Nunners I think that may be the easiest option. I just wanted more of a proactive response as opposed to a reactive approach.