# JavaScript - Check multiple SELECT for duplicate options

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, element, document

This question is based on [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160330/javascript-multiple-select-boxes-remove-selected-options)

When an option from one of the SELECT boxes were selected, I wanted the rest to be repopulated, without said option, but instead, is there an easy way to loop through all these select items, to ensure the same option hasn't been selected twice?

Thanks.

```
Person Number 1
<select name="person1">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

Person Number 2
<select name="person2">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

Person Number 3
<select name="person3">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Basic Overview:
JavaScript loop to ensure none of the options have been selected twice?

Comment: jQuery an option for you or do you need plain JS?

Comment: @j08691 plain JS unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function doAction(el) {

    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('person2').length; i++) {
        var v = (i != el.selectedIndex ? '' : 'disabled');

        document.getElementById('person2')[i].disabled = v;
        if (document.getElementById('person2').selectedIndex == el.selectedIndex)
            document.getElementById('person2').selectedIndex = 0;

        document.getElementById('person3')[i].disabled = v;
        if (document.getElementById('person3').selectedIndex == el.selectedIndex)
            document.getElementById('person3').selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Person Number 1
<select id="person1" onchange="doAction(this)" >
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/>
Person Number 2
<select id="person2">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/>
Person Number 3
<select id="person3">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I make a section for person #1, and then change my mind, what happens?

Comment: in other selects you can't select person #1, copy and paste the HTML here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events and try by your self

Comment: I'll put it a different way. If I pick #2 from the first select I can see it gets disabled from the other selects. Fine. However if I change my mind and pick #3 from the first select, now #3 AND #2 are disabled.

Comment: @Haroldis ,thanks this seems like a good solution, however the number of people is created on the fly, so there's not always three. Also, the Person# selector seems to ignore the formatting?

Comment: How you generate the id or name?

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
var x = document.getElementByName('person1').value;
var y = document.getElementByName('person2').value;
var z = document.getElementByName('person3').value;
```

you can get the values. Then, you have 3 items, to compare against all of them you just have to do 3 checks:

```
if(x == y || x == z || y == z){
    ...
}
```

Or you could throw all of the values into an array, and then splice out the first occurrence, and then check to see if it occurs again.

```
//get all selects
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var setOfPeople = [];
for(i in selects){
    setOfPeople[i] = selects[i].name;
}
var selections = [];
//put everything in an array
for(i in setOfPeople){
    selections[i] = document.getElementByName(setOfPeople[i]).value;
}
for(i in setOfPeople){
    var val = document.getElementByName(setOfPeople[i]).value;

    //make sure the element is in the selection array
    if(selections.indexOf(val) != -1){
        //rip out first occurrence
        selections.splice(selections.indexOf(val), 1);
    }

    //check for another occurrence
    if(selections.indexOf(val) != -1){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Once all of the selections are in an array, you could also just splice out the first element of that array, and look for another occurrence, instead of looping over the setOfPeople again, but I don't like modifying arrays that I'm looping over, so I didn't do it that way.

Comment: This is a good method, I just need to create the array element on the fly, after passing in number of people?

Comment: I would loop through all of the `<select>` tags, and then populate an array with the names of the elements, then you can do what I posted.
`var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');`
`var setOfPeople = [];`
`for(i in selects){setOfPeople[i] = selects[i].name;}`

Comment: Great, this sort of loop was exactly what I was looking for. Getting an error though: Nominees[i] = selects[i].name; (selects[i] is undefined). Also, there will be an instance where <select> tag will be disabled and should not be counted (person has withdrawn) - any easy workaround to this, otherwise I will remove this <select> and replace with plain text (Withdrawn)

Comment: For some reason this seems to be looping through too many times. On the final loop through, an undefined error occurs

Comment: Where are you defining `selects`? You have to make sure you're defining it before you start assigning values to it in the `for` loop, or else it won't be defined when you try to reference it later. Scopes suck. :( I'm not sure why you'd be getting an undefined error, my initial thought was that you might be getting an error splicing out the `-1`st element or splicing on an empty array, but Chrome handles that fine. Could it be a browser compatibility issue?

Comment: As per your suggestion 'var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');'. It's running through ALL the select boxes just fine, but then once it has looped through them all, it loops once more, hence the 'undefined' message

Comment: Ah okay, so as shown [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506), it's also returning length: 4 AND item function item() { [native code }